# Using 1 PFQuery (parse.com) for multi page app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm new to Objective c and right now I have a multi page app. Each page has a UITableView that is populated with the same PFQuery as the others. This results in API calls for each page. Is there a way to have the PFQuery in its own class so when I start/refresh the app, it populates all pages with just one query?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a myQuery class that has an array property of the results and then pass that from viewController to viewController in prepareForSegue.

myQuery would probably have a function executeQuery: which would repopulate queryResults, and you could set the viewControllers to observe queryResults to update their views.